# Struts 1 bean:write not working

Tags: jsp, struts-1

I have a jsp, and I want to control the 'disabled' attribute of a test field.
Is this syntax correct?
So far, the value isn't showing up when I run the page.

```
    <html:text property="startDate" maxlength="14" 
            disabled="<bean:write name='bbsInfoModel' property='waitMode'/>"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can't nest a full tag like that in another tag's attribute.  Try using a scriptlet, or $propertyName in the disabled attribute. (it's been a while since using struts.)

Or try this:

```
<html:text property="startDate" maxlength="14">
        <disabled><bean:write name='bbsInfoModel' property='waitMode'/></disabled>
 </html:text>
```

assuming your waitMode property returns a boolean.

If you can, check out the JSTL core taglib.

EDIT:  Try this:

```
disabled='${bbsInfoModel.waitMode}'
```

Last EDIT:  Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="startDate" maxlength="14" disabled="${bbsInfoModel.waitMode}" />
```

Comment: now i'm trying to use disabled='<c:out value="${bbsInfoModel.waitMode}"/>' />, but no go

Comment: Try this:  disabled='${bbsInfoModel.waitMode}'

Comment: OK, last try:  Instead of using an html:text property, do a straight html tag that isn't rendered by the JSP, and use the JSFT expression in the disabled attribute.  You may be running into the dreaded double-processing problem.